# XResources cannot be cast to XResources

Tags: android

Sometimes I have a crash on my app saying:

*android.content.res.XResources cannot be cast to android.content.res.XResources*

It happens on the ***setContentView()*** of my activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
    ...
}
```

There is nothing before this... Any help will be appreciate thanks.

Full stack (Replacing my package by *XXX*):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.activity.SplashActivity}:  
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.XResources cannot be cast to
    android.content.res.XResources
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3121)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
    Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
    android.content.res.XResources cannot be cast to android.content.res.XResources
    android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getInt (XResources.java:1400)
    android.transition.Transition.<init> (Transition.java:271)
    android.transition.TransitionSet.<init> (TransitionSet.java:85)
    android.transition.TransitionInflater.createTransitionFromXml (TransitionInflater.java:169)
    android.transition.TransitionInflater.inflateTransition (TransitionInflater.java:79)
    com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getTransition (PhoneWindow.java:2988)
    com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor (PhoneWindow.java:2904)
    com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView (PhoneWindow.java:2120)
    androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:717)
    androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
    androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    XXX.XXX.XXX.activity.SplashActivity.onCreate (SplashActivity.java:35)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7327)
    android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7318)
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1275)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3101)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3264)
    android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7063)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Hi @RomainBarbier any news on this? Could you resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi @Vall0n, no, not any news on this one... And since this crash for 1 user, I have not seen it again... sorry if you are facing it I cannot help you...

Comment: No problem at all. Thanks for the response!